# Slice dataframe columns into deciles and append to matrix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

tl;dr:  My code does what I want except for one element:  the rows which define `tick_slice` for each code block do not return the desired slices.  If you want to skip the details of my data, please skip to paragraph 4 below which begins with "My Question:".

I have the below code wherein I read csv file into a dataframe.  The data in the csv file is organized as follows:  The first row contains dates in the format YYYYMMDD, which are in descending value across ~350 columns.  In each column (below each date) are unique identifiers (somewhat like stock symbols).  Most of the columns have a different number of rows, ranging from a few hundred to a few thousand, and the identifiers are sorted from "best" to "worst."

My desire is to make a matrix (which will then be output to a new csv file).  The matrix is built as follows:  Beginning with the first column of the input csv data, get the top decile (10%) of identifiers and place them in the first column of the output matrix.  Next, move to the second column of the input csv data, get the top decile of identifiers from this column, and place these identifiers in the first column of the output matrix below the data placed there from step one.  Repeat this for the number of times given by the variable `hld_per`.  Then move to the right one column and repeat those steps.  So in my current code, the nested for loop would first cover columns 1:12 of the input csv data, then columns 2:13, etc.

I currently have ten blocks of this code repeated in order to create 10 output files, one for each decile, best to worst (the code below only shows the first two blocks of ten in order to save space; also, I know repeating this block 10 times is inefficient, but I'll fix that issue after I get the current code working as desired).

My Question:  The code below does most of what I want, but the lines which define `tick_slice` for each nested for loop don't work as desired.  Here is why:  Suppose for example a column has 35 identifiers.  As written, my first nine deciles will each contain 3 identifiers, and the tenth decile will have 8.  I would like the ten deciles to be as uniform in size as possible.  I have looked at qcut for this, but I can't figure out how to apply it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Also, if there's a completely different way to do this in pandas, I'm certainly open to any suggestions.

Partial Code:

```
import pandas as pd

hld_per = 12
quantiles = 10
permnos = pd.read_csv('Ranks.csv')
my_headers = list(permnos.columns)
total_cols = len(permnos.columns)

ports1 = []

for i in range(total_cols-(hld_per-1)):
    permlist = []
    for j in range(hld_per):
        tick_slice = int(permnos.iloc[:,i+j].count()/quantiles)
        col_slice = permnos.iloc[0:tick_slice, i+j].tolist()
        permlist = permlist + col_slice
    ports1.append(permlist)

matrix = pd.DataFrame(ports1)
matrix = matrix.T
matrix.columns = my_headers[0:len(matrix.columns)]
matrix.to_csv('ports1.csv', sep=',', index=False, header=True)

ports2 = []

for i in range(total_cols-(hld_per-1)):
    permlist = []
    for j in range(hld_per):
        tick_slice = int(permnos.iloc[:,i+j].count()/quantiles)
        col_slice = permnos.iloc[tick_slice:tick_slice*2, i+j].tolist()
        permlist = permlist + col_slice
    ports2.append(permlist)

matrix = pd.DataFrame(ports2)
matrix = matrix.T
matrix.columns = my_headers[0:len(matrix.columns)]
matrix.to_csv('ports2.csv', sep=',', index=False, header=True)
```

From this code, `permnos.head()` yields:

```
   20131231  20131130  20131031  20130930  20130831  20130731  20130630  \

0   93044.0   93044.0     13264     13264   89169.0   82486.0   91274.0   
1   79702.0   91515.0     90710     81148   47387.0   88359.0   93353.0   
2   85751.0   85724.0     88810     11513   85576.0   47387.0   85576.0   
3   85576.0   89169.0     81562     81562   81148.0   10294.0   10294.0   
4   13264.0   90710.0     82281     47387   11285.0   90710.0   47387.0
```

`matrix.head()` for `ports1` yields:

```
   20131231  20131130  20131031  20130930  20130831  20130731  20130630  \

0   93044.0   93044.0   13264.0   13264.0   89169.0   82486.0   91274.0   
1   79702.0   91515.0   90710.0   81148.0   47387.0   88359.0   93353.0   
2   85751.0   85724.0   88810.0   11513.0   85576.0   47387.0   85576.0   
3   93044.0   13264.0   13264.0   89169.0   82486.0   91274.0   85653.0   
4   91515.0   90710.0   81148.0   47387.0   88359.0   93353.0   91274.0
```

`matrix.head()` for `ports2` yields:

```
   20131231  20131130  20131031  20130930  20130831  20130731  20130630  \

0   85576.0   89169.0   81562.0   81562.0   81148.0   10294.0   10294.0   
1   13264.0   90710.0   82281.0   47387.0   11285.0   90710.0   47387.0   
2   90539.0   47387.0   93044.0   92805.0   82281.0   89169.0   66852.0   
3   89169.0   81562.0   81562.0   81148.0   10294.0   10294.0   89169.0   
4   90710.0   82281.0   47387.0   11285.0   90710.0   47387.0   93353.0
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can provide an example of the data as you've described it, as well as desired output.  See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's a bit confusing the way it's currently described.

Comment: I struggled with clarity here; hopefully this truncated example will help.  For the input file, suppose the first three columns have the date header 20161231, 20161130, and 20161031 respectively.  Below 20161231 are the identifiers 1 to 30 (30 identifiers); below 20161130 are 31 to 70 (40 identifiers); below 20161031 are 71 to 105 (35 identifiers).  The 1st 2 input columns are simple as they divide by 10; the 3rd is the trouble.  In column 1 of the output, you'd expect 1, 2, 3, 31, 32, 33, 34, 71, 72, 73 and maybe 74.  My question is how to best split column 3 into roughly equal buckets.

Comment: Can you post `permnos.head()`, and `matrix.head()` for `ports1` and `ports2`?

Comment: @andrew_reece I have posted this in the original question now (please let me know if this comment is unnecessary and should be deleted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to craft a solution for this using `qcut` but I have come up with an alternative solution which works to my specs.  Hopefully someone else will also find this of use.

```
import pandas as pd

hld_per = 12
quantiles = 10
permnos = pd.read_csv('Ranks.csv')
my_headers = list(permnos.columns)
total_cols = len(permnos.columns)

def slice_range(col_length, quantile):
    increment = col_length // 10
    remainder = col_length % 10 + 1
    addon = 0
    for i in range(quantile-1):
        remainder = max(0, remainder - 1)
        if remainder > 0:
            addon += 1
    start = (quantile - 1) * increment + addon  
    return start

for i in range(quantiles):
    ports = []
    for j in range(total_cols-(hld_per-1)):
        permlist = []
        for k in range(hld_per):
            col_len = permnos.iloc[:,j+k].count()
            start = slice_range(col_len, i+1)
            end = slice_range(col_len, (i+2))
            col_slice = permnos.iloc[start:end, j+k].tolist()
            permlist += col_slice
        ports.append(permlist)

    matrix = pd.DataFrame(ports).T
    matrix.columns = my_headers[0:len(matrix.columns)]
    matrix.to_csv("portstst5_" + str(i+1) + ".csv", sep=',', index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, then yes, `qcut()` can get you the splits you're looking for.

We'll start by building a sample `permnos` data frame.  This is based on OP `permnos.head()`, plus a couple of extra rows to illustrate column length heterogeneity.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'20130630': {0: 91274.0, 1: 93353.0, 2: 85576.0, 3: 10294.0, 4: 47387.0, 5: np.nan, 6: np.nan},
        '20130731': {0: 82486.0, 1: 88359.0, 2: 47387.0, 3: 10294.0, 4: 90710.0},
        '20130831': {0: 89169.0, 1: 47387.0, 2: 85576.0, 3: 81148.0, 4: 11285.0},
        '20130930': {0: 13264, 1: 81148, 2: 11513, 3: 81562, 4: np.nan},
        '20131031': {0: 13264, 1: 90710, 2: 88810, 3: 81562, 4: 82281},
        '20131130': {0: 93044.0, 1: 91515.0, 2: 85724.0, 3: 89169.0, 4: 90710.0, 5: 80000., 6: 900000.},
        '20131231': {0: 93044.0, 1: 79702.0, 2: 85751.0, 3: 85576.0, 4: 13264.0, 5: np.nan}}

permnos = pd.DataFrame(data)
permnos
   20130630  20130731  20130831  20130930  20131031  20131130  20131231
0   91274.0   82486.0   89169.0   13264.0   13264.0   93044.0   93044.0
1   93353.0   88359.0   47387.0   81148.0   90710.0   91515.0   79702.0
2   85576.0   47387.0   85576.0   11513.0   88810.0   85724.0   85751.0
3   10294.0   10294.0   81148.0   81562.0   81562.0   89169.0   85576.0
4   47387.0   90710.0   11285.0       NaN   82281.0   90710.0   13264.0
5       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   80000.0       NaN
6       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  900000.0       NaN
```

Consider what `qcut()` [returns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html):

> out : Categorical or Series or array of integers if labels is False
>   The return type (Categorical or Series) depends on the input: a Series of type category if input is a Series else Categorical.

We are passing in Series data, so we'll get a Series of type `category` as output.  For example:

```
n_bin = 3
out = pd.qcut(permnos["20130630"].dropna(), n_bin)
out
0      (89374.667, 93353.0]
1      (89374.667, 93353.0]
2    (60116.667, 89374.667]
3    (10293.999, 60116.667]
4    (10293.999, 60116.667]
Name: 20130630, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(10293.999, 60116.667] < (60116.667, 89374.667] < (89374.667, 93353.0]]
```

We can see how it handled the uneven splits for us; the three categories made buckets of 2, 1, and 2 data points, respectively.  Now, we can construct a boolean mask to get only the entries in the bucket we care about:

```
out == out.cat.categories[2] # categories are ordered small to large
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: 20130630, dtype: bool
```

With this approach, we should be able to grab the slice we want from each column by taking only those entries that are bucketed in our target quantile for each iteration.

We can condense things a bit by wrapping the core operation in a function, `construct_matrix()`.

**UDPATED**
(generalized for multiple matrices, per comments)

```
hld_per = 5
my_headers = list(permnos.columns)
total_cols = len(permnos.columns)

def construct_matrix(df, hld_per, total_cols, n_bin, colnames, start_pos, end_cat):
    ports = []
    started = start_pos

    for i in range(total_cols-(hld_per-1)):
        permlist = []
        for j in range(hld_per):
            out = pd.qcut(df.iloc[:,i+j].dropna(), n_bin)
            if not bool(started):
                end_pos = (out == out.cat.categories[start_pos]).sum()
            else:
                end_pos = start_pos + (out == out.cat.categories[end_cat]).sum()
            col_slice = df.iloc[start_pos:end_pos, i+j].dropna().tolist()
            permlist += col_slice
        ports.append(permlist)

    matrix = pd.DataFrame(ports).T
    matrix.columns = colnames[0:len(matrix.columns)]

    return matrix, end_pos
```

Given that we may want to build an arbitrary number of matrices based on `n_bin`, we set up a `construct_matrix()` loop, where each new `start_pos` after the first is `start_pos` + `end_pos`, as set inside the function from the previous iteration.  We'll store the resulting matrices in a list, `matrices`.

```
matrices = []
start_pos = 0
# number of qcut bins
n_bin = 3

for i in range(1, n_bin):

    end_cat = n_bin - i

    print("matrix: {}, start_pos: {}, end_cat: {}".format(i, start_pos, end_cat))

    matrix, start_pos = construct_matrix(permnos, hld_per, total_cols, n_bin, my_headers, 
                                         start_pos=start_pos, end_cat=end_cat)
    matrices.append(matrix)

    print(matrix)
    print()
```

Output:

```
matrix: 1, start_pos: 0, end_cat: 2
    20130630  20130731  20130831
0    91274.0   82486.0   89169.0
1    93353.0   88359.0   47387.0
2    82486.0   89169.0   13264.0
3    88359.0   47387.0   81148.0
4    89169.0   13264.0   13264.0
5    47387.0   81148.0   90710.0
6    13264.0   13264.0   93044.0
7    81148.0   90710.0   91515.0
8    13264.0   93044.0   85724.0
9    90710.0   91515.0   93044.0
10       NaN   85724.0   79702.0

matrix: 2, start_pos: 2, end_cat: 1
   20130630  20130731  20130831
0   85576.0   47387.0   85576.0
1   47387.0   85576.0   11513.0
2   85576.0   11513.0   88810.0
3   11513.0   88810.0   85724.0
4   88810.0   85724.0   89169.0
5       NaN   89169.0   85751.0
```

This should get you the (roughly) even splits you're looking for across columns and quantiles.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this with n_bin = 10 and generating matrix1 through matrix10.  matrix1 and matrix2 both work perfectly.  matrix3 through 10 do not work.  The reason, based on my testing, seems to be due to `start = (out == out.cat.categories[start_cat]).sum()`  (and end_cat) which generates the same `start` for matrix2 through 10. If I understand correctly, this is because each category occurs the same number of times (or close).  How can this be adjusted to, for example, acquire the 8th best bin?  Note - while the IDs are numeric, their row position (not value) determines the bin.

Comment: Are you updating `start_cat` and `end_cat` as you move through the matrices?  I only set up `best` and `second_best` as inputs to `construct_matrix()`, but as noted in my code you can either parameterize or hard-code the remaining quantiles (e.g. `third_best` and so on) to deal with subsequent matrices.

Comment: Yes, I updated within the function arguments.  e.g. For the eighth bin I used `matrix8 = construct_matrix(permnos, hld_per, total_cols, quantiles, my_headers, start_cat=(quantiles-7), end_cat=(quantiles-8))`. However, using `(quantiles-7)` in `start = (out == out.cat.categories[start_cat]).sum()` yields 3 (just as with `(quantiles - 1)`).

Comment: (cont) If I add `print(out == out.cat.categories[start])` to the code using `(quantiles-7)` as `start_cat`, the output from the first pass through the loop yields:0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
16    False
17    False
18    False
19     True
20    False
21    False
22     True
23    False
24    False
25    False
26    False
27    False
28    False
29    False
30    False
31    False
32     True

Comment: Ok, I see the issue.  On each new matrix, `start` needs to be `end` from the previous one.  Updating now.

Comment: Thanks. Changes with this edit present a few new issues. First, `start_pos` is now fixed throughout the loop in `construct_matrix`. The result is that some of the longer and shorter columns have `col_slice` that starts at the incorrect index. Second, because the columns have varying lengths, there are cases where `end_pos` in the first pass of the `construct_matrix` loop is different from the last pass (e.g. my first pass for matrix1 yields `end_pos` = 4, but the last pass = 3 because the last column has fewer rows). This creates an overlap in matrix2 as start_pos is 3 instead of 4.

Comment: (cont) Is it possible to use qcut to actually return the location of the first element of each n_bin for each column?  i.e. Where the first 10% begins, the second 10%, etc? Or perhaps there is a different method where we percentile each element of `permnos`?  If we were to percentile each element (by column, based on row position), we could create the matrices using cutoffs based on n_bin (e.g. x < 100/n_bin*i < y).  I very much appreciate all of your help with this.

Comment: Refer to the `retbins` argument in [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) for getting cut boundaries.  More generally, I'm going to let you take it from here - i've given you the basic solution, and from here on out it's just the normal slog of data munging to figure out all the specifics and edge cases.  That's more general project work than it is appropriate for SO.  It's a tricky problem, good luck!